# What keyboard layout is used by Logitech in Poland?

Tags: keyboard-layout, logitech-keyboard

For Apple, the default keyboard layout shipped in Poland is called ‘International English’. It has the ‘@‘ sign over ’2’ and an L-shaped enter key.
For Logitech, it is not quite clear. There is a keyboard layout called ‘US International’. It also has the ‘@‘ sign over ’2’ but the enter key appears to be rectangular instead of L-shaped.
Can you give a definite answer what is the name of the default Logitech keyboard layout for the Polish market?

This question is about the name that Logitech uses to describe the layout rather than what standard it is. A sample list of of the names used by Logitech can be found for example here: https://www.logitech.com/lang/pdf/roem/pn_and_layouts_keyboards.pdf

Comment: There are basically two main layouts in terms of key shapes: ANSI and ISO. ANSI is mostly used in the USA and ISO is mostly used everywhere else with a few exceptions. ISO has the vertical enter key and a short left-shift to accommodate an extra key. A full ANSI keyboard has 104 keys, a full ISO keyboard 105. laptops vary greatly from this standard and so do Apple I believe.  So you'll see ISO-UK which has " above 2 and £ above 3. There are other ISO variants and there is probably one for Poland but I don't know about it (hence long comment, not an answer). I'd guess Logitech sell ISO-PL.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794 for Apple layouts. Note "English" is [US] ANSI, International is [rest of the world] ISO. US International is likely to be ANSI.  If you're used to ISO, ANSI will annoy you;) @ or " over 2 is a Mac vs PC thing. Macs have @ over 2, PCs have " [again, this will annoy you]. The main difference between British & International is what's on shift/3 - pound £ or US pound # [the other is on opt/3 in both cases]. Get a picture of the Logitech & compare. Also make sure you get a keyboard for Mac, or you'll have to juggle modifier keys too.

Comment: You are right that I am looking for an ISO layout as vertical Enter keys are used through Europe. This is also why I am sceptical about the layout that Logitech calls ‘US International’ as it is likely to be ANSI with horizontal Enter key. But I don’t think Logitech has one called ISO-PL. While there are Czech or Hungarian layouts, Poland just uses the standard English keyboard. Like mentioned in my question, the Polish Apple Store ships with ‘International English’ by default (that is an ISO). So it is not quite clear what is the Logitech’s equivalent of Apple’s ‘International English‘.

Comment: In other words, I am looking for an American keyboard that is ISO, not ANSI. But Logitech does not appear to make them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

US International (Qwerty)

It is an ISO American keyboard (at least for Logitech MK295).